# How to check Reportid exist on ReportControl object or not using *ngif?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular7, angular-directive, angular-components

I work on angular 7 app I face issue I need to check

if Reportid exist or not on Report Control object using *ngIf on component.html.

on `report.component.ts`:

```
displayreport: any = {};
Reportid: string;

ngOnInit() {
  this._displayreport.GetReportControl(Reportid).subscribe((res: any) => {
      this.ReportControl = res;
      console.log("report control is" + JSON.stringify(this.ReportControl)
      });
  }
}
```

`this.ReportControl` return only one object as:

```
{"reportid":"2040","reportName":"financialAsset","reportType":"1"}
```

Expected result:

```
*ngIf="???????"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
displayreport: any = {};
Reportid: string;
ReportControl: any;
ngOnInit() {
  this._displayreport.GetReportControl(this.Reportid).subscribe((res: any) => {
      this.ReportControl = res;
      console.log("report control is" + JSON.stringify(this.ReportControl)
      });
  }
}
```

If you are checking if the value `reportid` is available in your response(res) in your html(ngIf), it can be achieved by following:

1. `*ngIf="ReportControl && ReportControl.reportid"`
2. `*ngIf="ReportControl?.reportid"`

Both work in a similar way, they check if `ReportControl` exists and then checks if corresponding `reportid` exists, this approach is more reliable as it avoids undefined property errors.

Answer (score 1):

Use as *ngIf = "Report controller?.reportid"

Comment: What do you mean without loop in yhis scenario

Comment: because this is object and have more property

Comment: Even though your object having different properties , ngIf will work as a single conditional check not as a loop. Hope I understand your concern correctly

Comment: when use two condition on ngif use and or && meaning *ngif(first condition and second) or using &&

Comment: You need to use &&